# Linux edit text commands to SQL update queries

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, linux

I was wondering if there is any equal SQL query for the below linux command?
(I want to update one column of my table which is a text field)

```
tr -cd '[:print:]\n' < in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't have anything like regexp replacement built in. Its `REPLACE()` function requires you to give a specific string that should be replaced, there's no `replace everything but` function. If you google for regexp replace user defined function you should be able to find something.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for prompt answer! :)